# Método Paint do Jframe não mostra os desenhos na tela

Tags: java, jframe

Eu sobrecarreguei o método `paint` do Jframe e estou utilizando a classe Graphics2D para tentar fazer os desenhos, mas nada está sendo desenhado na tela, pude ver com o *debugger* que o método é executado constantemente mas os desenhos não aparecem na tela, esse é o método:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) { 
    super.paint(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();

    g2d.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g2d.drawLine(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    g2d.dispose();
}
```

A classe principal implementa a interface `Runnable`, disparo uma *thread* e dentro do método `run` eu chamo o método `repaint()` do JFrame:

```
public void run(){
     repaint();
     try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
```

Aqui é o método `main` onde a *thread* é disparada:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.createGameWindow("Game");
    new Thread(game, "Game").start();
}
```

Já procurei por vários tutoriais atrás de um solução, no YouTube, sites de tutoriais etc, todos fazem exatamente o que estou fazendo mas nenhum funcionou,  qual pode ser o problema?

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que você está criando um novo objeto ao fazer:

> Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();

Por isso seu desenho não aparece na tela (ele está ocorrendo nesse outro `Graphics2D` que você criou).

Você deve simplesmente converter `g` em um objeto `Graphics2D`, via um `type cast`:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
```

De acordo com [essa outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179415/java2d-is-it-always-safe-to-cast-graphics-into-graphics2d), esse `type cast` é sempre válido desde o Java 1.2.

Lembrando que ao fazer esse `type cast`, deve-se remover o `g2d.dispose();` do final.